# program that writes N prime numbers

Tags: c++

How is the output of this program not affected if I replace `i++,j++,N--` with `++i,++j,--N`?

In both cases it returns N prime numbers? Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int N;
cin >> N;
for(int i=2;N>0;i++)
{
    bool IsPrime=true;
    for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(i % j == 0)
        {
        IsPrime=false;
        break;
        }
    }
    if(IsPrime)
    {
        N--;
        cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it would make a difference?

Comment: is there no difference between i++ and ++i?

Comment: What do you think the difference is?

Comment: @user3809253 there is a different in general, for the value it represents. It just doesn't matter for this particular example.

Comment: why doesnt it not affect the output , or does it have no relation?

Comment: There is a difference between i++ and ++i but this particular program is not affected by it. To see why, recall what this difference is, and what exactly it can affect.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i++ returns the original value then increments ..++i increments then returns the incremented value

Comment: @user3809253 _'then returns the '_ returns to what in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `a++` and `++a` is whether a is incremented **before** or **after** the expression is returned. Consider the following example:

```
int a = 5; 
cout << a++ << endl; //5
cout << a << endl; //6
a = 5;
cout << ++a << endl; //6
cout << a << endl; //6
```

You don't use the value of `a++`for your loop, so - as `cout << a << endl;` in my example, you will always get the variable to be increased by one.

The syntax of the for loop is as follows:

`for(initialize;condition;step){ /*block*/}`

The *initialize* part is run once at the beginning. For each loop, the *condition* is checked, and the *step* is executed afterward. It is not evaluated, and therefore doesn't infer with the condition.

Answer (score 3):

In a `for` loop it doesn't matter if you use `++x` or `x++` except that `++x` would be slightly faster since it won't create a temp variable.

Comment: for example if I use i++ the loop begins at i=2 then increments by 1 but if I use ++i the loop begins at i=3 am i right or what?

Comment: No in case of a for loop it will start at i=2 for the first run and then later on i=3 , i=4 etc. it's implemented that way. No matter if you use ++i or i++

Comment: @user3809253 _'am i right or what?'_ No. The 3rd statement in the for loop is executed **after** the loop body was executed.

Comment: I very much doubt that there is a performance difference for built in types. Compiler optimization works quite good for them.

Comment: Any half-way decent modern compiler should completely optimise away the difference between the two increment operations for built-in types. The reasons you should prefer pre-increment is (1) consistency with custom types where there may actually be a difference and (2) clearer semantics (you are expressing "increment x, please", not "make a copy of x, increment x, then give me the copy you just made, please").